# Can´t call the function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a calculator, where you write in a text input. For testing the code, I just made up a random count and a few "ifs". Here´s the code:

```
var res=0, operator, pattern, num1, num2
myText= "2~3+2"
pattern= /([\+\-\*\~\V/])/;
var nums= myText.split(pattern);

function makeCount() {
    num1= Number(num1);
    num2= Number(num2);

    if (operator=== "~") {
        num1= Math.pow(num1,num2);
        nums.splice(i-1, 3, num1);
    }
    if (operator=== "+") {
        num1= num1+num2;
        nums.splice(i-1, 3, num1);
    }
 }

function SrtLoop() { //checks all the numbers
    for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]=== "~") {
            num1=nums[i-1];
            num2=nums[i+1];
            operator="~";
            makeCount();
        }
        if (nums[i]=== "+") {
            num1= nums[i-1];
            num2= nums[i+1];
            operator="+";
            makeCount();
        }
    }
}

SrtLoop();
res=num1;
```

Before, I just put the the for loop, without a function, but I realized, after the program checked the operators, it would not check again. So I thought that putting the for loop inside a function, I would call it once, and after making the count it would call the for loop function again. Turns out that without the function, in the end, res=10 (expected), with the function, without calling it, res=undefined (expected), but calling the function destroys all the code and nothing appear in the screen.

Note: i am new here and sorry if my English is bad

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/).

Comment: @Alex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT) ... but I don't see how that's relevant to the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `makeCount` function has no reference to `i` whatsoever. You haven't declared `i` as a global variable (although that's not a great practice). You also haven't passed it as an argument to the `makeCount` function.

```
var res=0, operator, pattern, num1, num2
myText= "2~3+2"
pattern= /([\+\-\*\~\V/])/;
var nums= myText.split(pattern);

function makeCount(i) {
    num1= Number(num1);
    num2= Number(num2);

    if (operator=== "~") {
        num1= Math.pow(num1,num2);
        nums.splice(i-1, 3, num1);
    }
    if (operator=== "+") {
        num1= num1+num2;
        nums.splice(i-1, 3, num1);
    }
 }

function SrtLoop() { //checks all the numbers
    for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]=== "~") {
            num1=nums[i-1];
            num2=nums[i+1];
            operator="~";
            makeCount(i);
        }
        if (nums[i]=== "+") {
            num1= nums[i-1];
            num2= nums[i+1];
            operator="+";
            makeCount(i);
        }
    }
}

SrtLoop();
res=num1;
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f2yrxgu/

It doesn't log anything as I really don't understand what you're doing here. However, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is undefined in function `makeCount()`. Modify as follows:

```
function makeCount(i) {
   //Your code
}
```

Modify the calls as follows:

```
makeCount(i);
```